# BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64 even I have lower the gradleversion

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

:\Users\rethn.gradle\caches\8.0.1\scripts\1mrpar4986zd3t4i3s9z4ro8x).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 64

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 651ms
error Failed to install the app.
my application is not getting installed in my AVD

I tried to install the react-native app in my AVD but it is failing due to a build error, I tried lowering my gradle version from 8.0.1 to other lower version in the gradle-wrapper.properties still it is not working . help me resolve the issue ,

Thanks